# Bug: Gazebo segmentation fault - PR2 spawn - Ubuntu Precise Lucid

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ROS Fuerte, Gazebo 1.6.16

Hi all,

I've been trying to get Gazebo running on another laptop. 
I tried Ubuntu 12.04.1 Precise 64bit, 
Ubuntu 10.04.4 Lucid 32bit and 64bit, 
various versions of NVidia proprietory drivers from 195.xx and 304.xx series.

In all cases, Gazebo crashes with segmentation fault when getting near the end of completely spawning the PR2. 
In this case in seems to be from **libc.so.6**. 
(Other software configurations have segfaulted in a Boost or OpenGL library.)

This bug report focuses on **Ubuntu 10.04.4 64bit**:

```
$ glxinfo
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro FX 3500/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1.2 NVIDIA 195.36.24
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

Executing:

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

with Gazebo set to debug. That loads fine, until I spawn the PR2 using:

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

which causes a segfault in the first console.

See backtrace below. Problem in libc.so.6 after calling Ogre::GLFrameBufferObject::initialise  ?

While leaving the crashed programs running

```
ps -ef | grep gz
```

produces

```
/bin/bash /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/scripts/gdbrun /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/dbworth/.ros/log/02fc2ece-601f-11e2-8f89-00c0ca21e421/gazebo-2.log -s /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so -s /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so
gdb -x /tmp/gdbrun.20686.7.tmp /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/dbworth/.ros/log/02fc2ece-601f-11e2-8f89-00c0ca21e421/gazebo-2.log -s /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so -s /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so
```

Also see below for output of:

```
thread apply all bt
```

I was going to try to build the normal and HG versions from source, but

```
 hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo gazebo
```

gives

```
requesting all changes
abort: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Cheers, 
David.

[image description http://i46.tinypic.com/e00efs.png](http://i46.tinypic.com/e00efs.png)

**Backtrace:**

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/c54deb3bb883f37d19df10f0d140e09a

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/872/bug:-gazebo-segmentation-fault---pr2-spawn---ubuntu-precise-lucid/) by [dbworth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/144/dbworth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please try ROS Groovy, Ubuntu 12.04.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0